# Integral of second-order derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

How can I perform the integration of second-order T ($\int \partial^2T=0$), so that I can arrive at equation 5.85, where T is a variable of $\xi$ and $\eta$?

[image]

Here is what I get:
$$ \int \partial^2T=0 $$
$$ T\partial + C = 0 $$

and I'm not sure what to do with the $T\partial$. Doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: If I tell you to solve $\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial \xi} = 0$, can you write down something that actually makes sense?

Comment: I think so. Wouldn't it be $T = C$, where C is a function of xi? Or am I wwwway of?

Comment: No, the whole point is that the function $T$ is independent of $\xi$, so you get $$\int \frac{\partial T}{\partial \xi}d\xi = \int 0\,d\xi = C,$$ but in this computation $\eta$ is fixed, and so $C = C(\eta)$ is an arbitrary function of $\eta$. Can you proceed now? Integrate your equation first with respect to $\eta$ (fixing $\xi$) because $\partial^2 T/\partial\xi\partial\eta = \partial (\partial T/\partial\eta)/\partial\xi$.

Comment: Side question, can you remind me why is the partial of T wrt xi is integrated wrt "non partial" $d\xi$ ?

Comment: Integrals are written with $dx$, $dy$, etc. The partial derivative notation is just to remind you that other variables are held fixed. Of course, when you do an iterated integral (rather than a double integral) $dx\,dy$, you typically integrate first with respect  to the inner variable (fixing the outer), etc. I can't teach a whole multivariable calculus class here in comments. :P

Comment: O-oh! Got it. That's what I needed to hear. You are doing just swell teaching calculus in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with what you are given:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta }T(\xi,\eta)\right) = 0$$
Integrate once with respect to $\xi$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta }T(\xi,\eta) = C_1(\eta)$$
where $C_1$ is an arbitrary function of $\eta$ (since it vanishes if you apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi}$).

Then integrate once with respect to $\eta$:
$$T(\xi,\eta) = \tilde{ C_1}(\eta) + C_2(\xi)$$
where $C_2$ is an arbitrary function of $\xi$ (since it vanishes if you apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}$) and $\tilde{C_1}$ is an antiderivative of $C_1$.

Now just call $\tilde{\psi} = \tilde{C_1}$ and $\tilde{\varphi}=C_2$.

Comment: Doing this I get $$ T = C_1 * \eta + C_2 $$
I'm a bit lost on the antiderivative there. Any help?

Comment: This would be right if $C_1$ were a constant, but it's not -- it's a function of $\eta$ (likewise, $C_2$ isn't constant, it's a function of $\xi$). But since you don't know what it is, you can't give a specific function for *its* antiderivative. You can only write $\int C_1(\eta)\;d\eta$. But that's awkward, so I just wrote a tilde over $C_1$ to indicate that it is really just another arbitrary function (with some limitations).

Comment: Oh, right! When integrating wrt xi, the constant is wrt the other variable.

Comment: (continued) When you're taking antiderivatives, you have to think to yourself "What could go here so that when I take its derivative, I get what I started with?" This is made more complicated by the fact that these are *partial* derivatives, so the usual arbitrary additive constant of integration gets replaced by an arbitrary additive function of all other variables. You always remember that you check this by going backwards and taking a (partial) derivative to verify that you get what you started with.

Comment: (continued) Your gut instinct is probably pretty close, just remember that it's a little more general so these are functions, not just constants, that you tack on to get the general antiderivative.